# I'm trying to create a random chore generator but it doesn't seem to print correctly

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create a chore generator that will randomly select a chore, and then randomly select a more detailed chore after that.  For example, one of the chores is 'Walk Dog', and then i want the computer to pick a place for me to walk.

```
import random
import time

print ('Hello!')

choices = ('Play PC', 'Walk Dog', 'Tidy house')
games = ('Siege', 'GTA', 'Minecraft')
places = ('Park up the road', 'Park near gym', 'park near school')

print (random.choice(choices))
if random.choice(choices) == 'Play PC':
  print (random.choice(games))
if random.choice(choices) == 'Walk Dog':
  print (random.choice(places))
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the first choice inside a variable - not take another random pick:

```
import random
import time

print ('Hello!')

choices = ('Play PC', 'Walk Dog', 'Tidy house')
games = ('Siege', 'GTA', 'Minecraft')
places = ('Park up the road', 'Park near gym', 'park near school')

c = random.choice(choices)
print(c)
if c == 'Play PC':
  print (random.choice(games))
elif c == 'Walk Dog':  
  print (random.choice(places))
```

By picking twice you might get (randombly) two different results.

Outputs 3 runs:

```
Hello!
Play PC
Minecraft

Hello!
Walk Dog
Park near gym

Hello!
Tidy house
```

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `random.choice(places)` will produce another random choice, potentally different from the previous one. You should call it once, and then evalute it:

```py
choide = random.choice(places)
print (choice)
if choice == 'Play PC':
  print (random.choice(games))
elif choice == 'Walk Dog':
  print (random.choice(places))
```